# iOS Swift - pull tray open to expand content

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've been searching for a library or sample project that implements the following functionality, but unfortunately haven't been able to find much. Could anyone share any thoughts or point me in a general direction if experienced something similar?

I'd like create a pull-out view controller/tray whose interaction is very similar to the Google Maps iOS app (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1QHt.png). When a user taps or pulls-up the snippet pane, the view expands until fully maximized. Essentially the same interaction as seen in the Maps app.

I'm happy to implement from-scratch if a library doesn't exist, but regardless wanted to seek any suggestions/insights before getting underway.

Thanks again for your help & advice!

Comment: I don't think that you need a library to do this. Simply put your snippet pane in a `UIPopoverController`, add a single-tap gesture handler to it, and in the gesture's action, animate the rest of the content in above it.

Comment: Okay thanks @NRitH, I'll give this a try

Comment: In order to obtain the drag effect, would utilizing the UIPanGestureRecognizer be a good approach?

Comment: Both, maybe. The tap gesture would animate it to full size in a non-interactive way, while the pan gesture would be an interactive animation that tracks the velocity of the user's gesture.